# Implement Comparable<T> in a generic superclass

Tags: java, generics

I have an abstract generic superclass which I extend to make concrete classes with IDs of a specific type:

```
public abstract class AbstractEntity<I> {
  ...
  private I id;
  private String name;
  ...
}
```

I create the concrete classes like this:

```
public class User extends AbstractEntity<Long> {...}
```

Now I want to make the concrete classes comparable to other instances of themselves (and no other type--this should be enforced at compile time). By default the `compareTo` method should just sort by name so I want to add it in the superclass to avoid repeating code. The only way I've come up with to do this is with this ugly construct:

```
public abstract class AbstractEntity<I,T> implements Comparable<AbstractEntity<I,T>> {
  ...
  private I id;
  private String name;
  ...
  @Override
  public int compareTo(AbstractEntity<I,T> o) {
    ...
  }
}
```

...

```
public class User extends AbstractEntity<Long,User> {...}
```

I think this is ugly because now in order to extend the superclass you need to repeat the concrete class name again as a type parameter for itself, which is odd and counterintuitive. Is there a more elegant way to accomplish the same thing that I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Technically, one could "break the implied contract" and create a concrete class which was comparable to some other class with something like "class Foo extends AbstractEntity<Long,User>", but I'm not that worried about cases where people go out of their way to write garbage.

Comment: Is there any reason you must use `Comparable` rather than `Comparator`?  The `Comparator` method seems more suitable for use with inheritable types.  If you will need to be able to compare items without having a `Comparator` handy, but you will control the types in question, it might also be helpful to define an interface which allows an object to be asked for a `Comparator` that is suitable for use with it.  If one has a `Comparator` that can handle all items in an array, one can cleanly sort the array even if the items are of different types.

Comment: @supercat - Mainly because it would require fewer client-side changes to reap the benefits. If I used a Comparator, the client code would have to acquire the Comparator and explicitly use it (either by creating a collection that uses it or by passing it to a sort function).  They would have to do this everywhere they want to sort. This way, if the client code happens to place the objects of this type in a naturally sorted Collection (or they call a natural sort function), it will just start working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're looking for is the "self type", but this can't be achieved in Java. The closest you can come is using a recursively bound type parameter that is *supposedly* the self type:

```
public abstract class AbstractEntity<I, E extends AbstractEntity<I, E>> implements Comparable<E> {
    ...
    private I id;
    private String name;
    ...
    public final String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    ...
    @Override
    public int compareTo(E otherEntity) {
        final String otherName = otherEntity.getName();
        ...
    }
}

public final class User extends AbstractEntity<Long, User> { }
```

I would recommend against this pattern though, as it's confusing and can easily be abused. For example:

```
public final class EvilUser extends AbstractEntity<Long, AnotherUser> { }
```

My advice: just stick to implementing `Comparable` on an individual-entity basis.

Comment: +1 for "_implement Comparable in the concrete entity classes_" (and I love to over-engineer ;)

Comment: @jahroy - Normally I'd agree, but I oversimplified my use case a bit to make my head spin less when phrasing the question. Suffice it to say that extenders of the superclass will have little reason to add any additional functionality to the concrete classes--the concrete classes are normally completely empty. The sole purpose of creating the subclasses is to create different categories of the same thing, with different types. Because of this it makes sense to implement Comparable in the superclass, so extenders of the superclass need not do anything.

Comment: @Paul - I'll admit that sometimes my head spins when thinking about some of the more nuanced aspects of generics, but what advantage does this form have over my original solution? It does not address the problem I asked about. The client code (extending class) syntax is exactly the same, and if anything the superclass appears even more confusing. It does not appear (to my spinning head) to be any more type-safe. I also mentioned in the comment that you could craft a class that was comparable to another class, but as I said I'm not worried about people going out of their way to write garbage.

Comment: @Paul - Your solution does at least make the compareTo method take exactly the right type. Thanks!

Comment: Best answer, because even though it appears you can't clean up the extend syntax, it did make the `compareTo` type exact. I wonder why there isn't a self type?

Answer (score 2):

No. This is how you're supposed to do it. Putting the class itself in the parameter description is actually a normal thing to do in a situation like this one.

Comment: It's hard to give a "thumbs up" to a "you can't" type answer without some sort of supporting evidence. Can you give a link to a similar issue where this was the consensus?

Comment: @AlvinThompson - It's easy to find evidence that supports this answer.  Look at the API documentation for any class that implements Comparable.  [Example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html): `Byte implements Comparable<Byte>`

Comment: @jahroy - that's not the same thing; in that case the concrete class is implementing Comparable. If anything, that's an argument that Comparable should be implemented by the concrete classes, not evidence that this is impossible.

Comment: @AlvinThompson - Ok... that's fine.  I was offering evidence to support that it's "_a normal thing to do in a situation like this one_" not to support that something is impossible.  I would normally say you _should_ implement Comparable in the subclasses, but you've already explained why that isn't optimal (or sensible) in your comments under Paul's answer.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for

```
public abstract class AbstractEntity<I> implements
        Comparable<AbstractEntity<I>> {
    private I id;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(AbstractEntity<I> o) {

        if (o != null && !o.getClass().equals(getClass())) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported instance type "
                    + o.getClass());
        }

        return 0;
    }

}

public class User extends AbstractEntity<Long> {
}
```

Comment: The problem here is that the concrete class would be comparable with any other concrete class with the same ID type at compile time, and defer the check until runtime. I want concrete classes to be comparable only with others of the exact same class, and enforced at compile time to avoid unneeded runtime errors.

Answer (score 0):

> Now I want to make the concrete classes comparable to other instances
>   of themselves (and no other type--this should be enforced at compile
>   time).

Why? Generics is not there for you to make arbitrary restrictions. Generics is only for enforcing *type safety* (i.e. the elimination of casts; avoiding ClassCastException). Arbitrarily requiring it to not be comparable to other types serves no *type-safety* purpose, and thus cannot be done.

If the comparison does not depend on any subclass features, then `AbstractEntity<I>` is comparable to all `AbstractEntity<I>`, in which case it should be declared like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractEntity<I> implements Comparable<AbstractEntity<I>>
```

> The problem here is that the concrete class would be comparable with
>   any other concrete class with the same ID type at compile time

So what? The comparison is perfectly type-safe. If you don't want to compare one concrete class to another, then don't. If someone else wants to compare one concrete class to another, then great for them. Why does this matter to you?

p.s. The code you posted, `public abstract class AbstractEntity<I,T> implements Comparable<AbstractEntity<I,T>>` also does not enforce that one class only compares to itself, because there is no guarantee that a class must extend it with itself as the second parameter.

Comment: @newact - "there is no guarantee that a class must extend it with itself as the second parameter". This has already been mentioned several times, including by me in the first comment right below the question.

Comment: @newact - "Generics is not there for you to make arbitrary restrictions." Generics are there to provide a compile-time contract as to what types should be passed to and from a method. That's exactly what I'm doing. The rest of what you wrote is simply argumentative and not constructive. If you don't agree with my solution, provide a better one. Arguing that I shouldn't care serves no purpose. I agree that my solution was inelegant. That's the reason I asked this question in the first place.

Comment: @AlvinThompson: No, Generics is only for the purposes of avoiding `ClassCastException` by avoiding casts. For example, if you have a `Foo<T>` which as a method `T get()`, then when you have a `Foo<String>` and call `get()`, you know you get a `String`. Without generics you would need a cast. *That*'s the purpose of generics. There is no cast in your code. There is no cast to avoid.

Comment: @newact - Generics do *not* enforce type safety; they merely provide a compile-time contract on what types data should be. Enforcing type safety implies that generics work at runtime. Generics don't exist at runtime.

Comment: @AlvinThompson: Generics enforce *compile-time type safety*. That is, given that you don't do unchecked casts, it will provably not have `ClassCastException`.

Comment: @AlvinThompson: Let me ask you, why doesn't the `Comparable` interface somehow "require" its type parameter to be the same type as the class that implements it? Wouldn't that be so convenient in that you don't have to "repeat" in `class Foo implements Comparable<Foo>`? The answer is that 1) this is not possible in Java, and 2) it serves no *type-safety* purpose. If someone writes a class that can compare to another, it is still type safe. If a generic *method* should require that a type be comparable to itself, then *that method* can require this as part of its type bound.

Comment: @newact - What you just said is contradictory. ClassCastException is a runtime exception. Once again, generics merely provide the semantics for a (compile time) contract. *They do not enforce that contract.* This is not constructive.

Comment: @AlvinThompson: No, you are the one who is not being constructive. ClassCastException can occur when there is a cast. When using Generics, the casts are still inserted in bytecode in the same place. However, Generics provides a *compile-time* proof that the cast will not cause ClassCastException. Thus, it is no longer necessary to explicitly write the cast in Generics.

Comment: @jahroy - Yup, and the pontification has all come from a single source. He really should get a blog instead of trying to preach to people who simply want answers.